# How to remove the double quotes around numbers in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, regexp-replace

I have several strings similar like this

```
"apple cost": "2.78" 
"orange cost": "12.59"
"melone cost": "42.12"
```

the number can change/is variable and I want to remove the double quotes around the number. So the result should be like this

```
"apple cost": 2.78
"orange cost": 12.59
"melone cost": 42.12
```

The price are between 0.01 and 999.99 and the text varies only in relation to the name of the fruit and should always be in the form

"fruit name coast":. This part of the string does not need to be changed

How can I do this in Python?

I tried this with a expression like this, but the double quotes werent removed.

```
string = '"apple cost": "2.78"'
string = string.replace('"apple cost": "([0-9]).([1-9]|[0-9][0-9])"', '"apple cost": ([0-9]).([1-9]|[0-9][0-9])')¨
string = string.replace('"orange cost": "([0-9]).([1-9]|[0-9][0-9])"', '"orange cost": ([0-9]).([1-9]|[0-9][0-9])')
```

Comment: Do you have more examples of how your input looks like? Any boundary cases? Any other surrounding text that needs to be ignored? Is this JSON input?

Comment: more examples are ´
`code` 
"orange cost": "12.59"
"melone cost": "42.12"

the price are between 0.01 and 999.99. the text varies only in relation to the name of the fruit and should always be in the form "<fruit name> coast":. This part of the string does not need to be changed

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the examples and corresponding results there? Can you also clarify if the whole input structure is JSON? As your question is currently phrased, it looks like you want to only match **apple** costs, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you where you want to go?

```
strings = ['"apple cost": "2.78"', 
           '"orange cost": "12.59"', 
           '"melone cost": "42.12"']

return_dict = {sub[0]: float(sub[-1].split('"')[-2]) for sub in [string.split(":") for string in strings]}

for key, val in return_dict.items():
    print (f'{key} : {val}')
```

Producing this output:

```
"apple cost" : 2.78
"orange cost" : 12.59
"melone cost" : 42.12
```

This approach keeps the numbers as strings, just removes the double quotes - which is specifically what you've asked about. You could of course also convert the numbers from strings to floats if you wished, like so:

```
return_dict = {sub[0].split('"')[-2]: float(sub[-1].split('"')[-2]) for sub in [string.split(":") for string in strings]}
```

**EDIT**

If you're looking to return a list of strings identical to the input ones EXCEPT for the removal of the double quotes around the number, this should work:

```
newstrings = []

for string in strings:
    key, val = string.split(':')
    key += ':'
    val = val.split('"')[-2]
    newstrings.append(f'{key} {val}')
    
for newstring in newstrings:
    print (newstring)
```

producing the output:

```
"apple cost": 2.78
"orange cost": 12.59
"melone cost": 42.12
```

This obviously assumes that your input data will always look the same as the sample of data you've provided... If you have more edge cases, please provide them for a more expansive answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer and your help. Unfortunately it is not the expected solution, because I will need the douple quotes around the fruits and the colon after the fruits. I want only remove the quotes around the numbers

Comment: OK - exactly what form do you want your output to take? Do you want your output to be a single string? a list of strings? a dict?

Comment: Answer updated to take in a list of strings and return a list of strings, where each string is identical to the input string EXCEPT for the removal of the double quotes around the number...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 capture groups and use those in the replacement using `\1\2`

```
("[^"]* cost":\s*)"(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)"
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `"[^"]* cost":\s*` Match `"`, then optional chars other than `"`, then `cost":` followed by optional whitespace chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `"` Match the double quote that you don't want to keep
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match 1-3 digits and optionally match `.` and 1-2 digits
- `)` Close group 2
- `"` Match the double quote that you don't want to keep

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccq40A/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OaNkA5)

Example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"(\"[^\"]* cost\":\s*)\"(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\""
 
s = ("\"apple cost\": \"2.78\" \n"
    "\"orange cost\": \"12.59\"\n"
    "\"melone cost\": \"42.12\"")
 
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2", s))
```

Output

```
"apple cost": 2.78 
"orange cost": 12.59
"melone cost": 42.12
```